# Did Jack die at the end from a shotgun wound?

Tags: plot-explanation, uncaged

In the movie [*Uncaged*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3562786/), Jack (the main character and a werewolf) gets shot with a shotgun.  Earlier in the film, Jack's friend is shown breaking up a piece of silver and loading it into the shotgun shells.  It is only an assumption if it worked or not.

Immediately after we see Jack (as a werewolf) lunge for the the girl that shot him and all we see is a blast coming from the gun.  The scene then cuts to the next day and we see  Jack's uncle coming home and discovering a girl with a gun in her lap and Jack laying beside her.  The way that his body is positioned, you cannot see any wounds or blood from the shotgun blast.

Jacks's uncle walks closer to them and looks at Jack and then at the girl (seeing that she has a wound from Jack from the night before) and tells her "Welcome to the family."

There is nobody in the family besides Jack and his uncle.  I understand that he would say something like this because she was obviously bitten/scratched and will turn into a werewolf also.

**Did Jack's uncle say this to her because he knew that Jack was still alive?**  **Is there any additional information from filmmakers/movie scripts about this film to suggest what Jack's fate was at the end?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are several reasons as to why Jack is more than likely still alive:**

- When he was shot, the scene did not actually show Jack getting shot, it just showed Rose firing the gun while Jack was lunging towards her after he turned into a werewolf.
- There is a reason why we don't fully see Jack while he is laying next to Rose.  We don't see if he is bleeding or hurt or anything.  The top of his head is shown to where you can see his hair and his clothes are covering up the rest of him.  His face is not shown at all.
- Jack's uncle Mike presumably knew that he was still alive.  This is why he made the "Welcome to the family" comment to Rose.  Not only was rose infected by Jack and will turn into a werewolf herself, but he sees Jack laying next to her and welcomes her into their "werewolf" family.

Uncle Mike had basically planned all along for Jack to come and live with him after Jack learns that he is himself a werewolf after his 18th birthday.  Jack is the only family that Uncle Mike has left.  Uncle Mike did not seem distressed at all at the site of Jack laying there.